# Definition of countdown

Tags: definition

> 1    n-sing  A countdown is the counting aloud of numbers in reverse order before something happens, especially before a spacecraft is launched.
> also no det
> **The countdown has begun for the launch later today of the American space shuttle...**
> 2    n-count  The countdown to an event is the period of time leading up to the event.
> ...the countdown to the next election.
> https://mobile-dictionary.reverso.net/en/english-cobuild/countdown

I think the first example sentence is in the wrong place. It actually illustrates the second definition: counting aloud of numbers only lasts a few seconds.  If it has already started, then the launch can't be later in the day.

Do you agree with me? Thanks.

Comment: It's not always saying numbers aloud. It can also be a visual display of the time until the action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. The countdown for launch can begin hours before launch.

> Follow along with the countdown! The NASA Launch Blog is the only place online to get latest-breaking launch information directly from Kennedy Space Center in Florida. **Live countdown coverage will begin about six hours prior to launch** and will conclude about 10 minutes after liftoff, when orbit insertion is complete. Coverage includes frequent updates on the countdown status and videos of key events.

--[NASA Blog](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/launch/countdown101.html)

So if your dictionary example came after the countdown had started, then it is accurate.

Comment: The Apollo 11 countdown was scheduled for 93 hours, but the launch director took advantage of extra time and inserted four rest periods totalling 40 hours.